# Calculate a specific day's Date to another date, and print their difference?

Tags: javascript, date, frameworks

Today is 3/26/2016. I want to Print out how many days are until  4/05/2016 ex.

The answer is 10 days.
I want to do this with Javascript Code.

With standard javascript or with the use of a Library or Framework.
Just to calculate the Difference between two dates.
Easy, no too complicated.

InsertDateHere     -------         3/26/2016

InsertDateHere  ------  4/05/2016

ResultHere     -------------- AnswerHere ("10" ex.)

if anyone can help, please Do. Thanks a lot People!

Answer (score 1):

Moment.js is a helpful library that can also handle timezones and DST. The method that you're looking for is [difference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/).

If this is the only date-handling that you'll be doing, it's likely not worth it to pull in a library. You can handle this easily with a simple function.

```
var diffInDays = function diffInDays (dateA, dateB) {
  var difference = dateA - dateB;
  return Math.floor(Math.abs(difference / (1000*60*60*24)));
};

diffInDays(Date.parse('3/26/2016'), Date.parse('4/05/2016'));
// > 10
```

Comment: Note that it is strongly recommended **not** to use the Date constructor (or Date.parse) to parse strings. If using a parser (and moment.js has a good one) then the format should always be specified.